# soapUI does not catch validation error

Tags: regex, wsdl, soapui, xml-validation

I have a restricted type with base string:

```
 <simpleType name="stringto1">
    <restriction base="string">
       <pattern value="[АБВГ2134-]"/>
    </restriction>
 </simpleType>
```

And a field with this type:

```
<element maxOccurs="4" minOccurs="1" name="P5" type="tns:stringto1"/>
```

But i can write EVERYTHING what i want in this field and the validation is OK!
And there IS validation error on the server.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special character `-` in `regex` is for specify a `range` like `[a-z]`. If you want to use `-` as a simple character you must escape it with `\` as `\-`, so try with the follow `regex` as `pattern`:

```
 <simpleType name="stringto1">
    <restriction base="string">
       <pattern value="[АБВГ2134\-]"/>
    </restriction>
 </simpleType>
```

Additionally `SOAPUI` isn't validating your xml because doesn't compile your `pattern`, you can see this in the `SOAPUI` log, where the follow error message is displayed:

`15:57:51,883 WARN  [SchemaUtils] Error: ...\wsdl.wsdl: 0: warning: pattern-regex: The regular expression '[????2134-]' is malformed: '-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'.`

Note that `????` it's because my charset encoding doesn't recognize `АБВГ` characters, I supouse that in your case escaping `-` as `\-`will be enough.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks, but some sources said, that `-` is only special when there are symbols before AND after it, so are that sources wrong?

Comment: I think in java regex that `-` is special character only between square brackets `[]` outside of square brackets are a normal character. In your case you're expression is in `[]` so it's special character.